# What is causing my website converted to APK pages to stick when scrolling?

Tags: apk

I converted my website to an APK and it installs fine - the problem is that when trying to scroll up or down - the page sticks and the page refreshes to a page not available - the live site works perfect.

Comment: It's not clear which software you were using to do any of this. Please make sure you state your problems in a clear, unambiguous way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use momentum scrolling. I don't know exactly what can cause your issue, but

> Android 3+ and iOS 5+ implemented a new property called overflow-scrolling that enables momentum scrolling. And it works beautifully.

Look here: http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-perceived-performance/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a service from GoNative that packages mobile web sites into APKS - kind of a wrapper to allow mobile sites to function like apps. One of the configuration options was to use "web pool" services that cached pages to allow for faster processing - I deleted that feature and the site/app works fine.

Comment: Thanks found answer